# The LCD is blank with my 500mm/F8 Nikon mirror lens on my Nikon D200 when I shoot

Tags: nikon, live-view, lcd, mirror-lens

When I use my Nikon 500 MM mirror lense I do not get a view of my subject through the LCD, I have to use the viewfinder.  I would prefer to see the image via the LCD on my D200 before I take the photo

Answer (score 5):

You can't, the Nikon D200 is too old to be able to read the sensor in realtime in order to show you the image on the LCD screen.

That feature was introduced with the D300 / D90